# How to populate nested array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got stuck at populating my array... this is what i get from my `Terminal.find()` function:

```
{ _id: 5a7300046f18140d5081be83,
  type: 5a71a22b0d4a2d0ec3b91edc,
  serial: '213',
  macAddress: 'E1:12:BE:82:12',
  barcode: '1243w464563',
  dateArrival: 2018-02-01T11:54:15.870Z,
  firmware: 5a71a2030d4a2d0ec3b91edb,
  installedAt: 5a61e547922c6d28e324d775,
  installedAtBranch: 5a7054713fe20c0c5a94fb11,
  __v: 0,
  deleted: false,
  activated: true }
```

So i want to get the correct information, when a user searches for the terminal. This is why i have to use `populate()`. Difficult for me now is to populate things deeper inside the array. So the first Object `type` has a `readMethod`, a `layout` and `interfaces` - i have to populate those three, but i don't know how. This is aggravated by the fact that `interfaces` is an Object inside my Database. So my `type` looks like this:
[image]

I think if someone can show me how to populate `type` with all of its `interfaces` i can achive the rest on my own.

Thanks in advance!

---

I found the answer on my own by searching deeper inside google:

```
Terminal.findOne({'barcode': barcode})
        .populate({ 
            path: 'type',
            populate: [{
                path: 'user',
                model: 'User'
            },
            {
                path: 'method',
                model: 'Method',
            },
            {
                path: 'layout',
                model: 'Layout'
            },
            {
                path: 'interfaces',
                model: 'Interface'
            }]
        })
        .populate('firmware')
        .populate('customerId')
        .populate('branchId')
        .exec( function (err, terminal) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.json({ terminal });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using mongoose then I think your model should look like following or it must be like following

**Terminal Type Schema**

```
var terminalTypeSchema = new Schema({
    articlenumber: { type: Number, default: something },
    readMethod: Schema.ObjectId,
    layout: Schema.ObjectId,
    interfaces: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
mongoose.model('TerminalType', terminalTypeSchema);
```

**Interface Schema**

```
var interfaceSchema = new Schema({
    // some vars
});
mongoose.model('Interface', interfaceSchema);
```

Now run following query

```
TerminalType.findOne({ _id: terminalTypeId})
.populate('interfaces') // <==
.exec(function(err, terminalTypes){
    // You can achieve the rest on your own.
});
```